# Need to select rows from one partial and append them to rows in another partial in ASP.NET MVC 3 and knockout.js based system

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, knockout.js, partial-views

I am developing an ASP.NET MVC website with knockoutjs. For one of the screens, we need two partial views (let's say Partials A and B) in two divs respectively. Each partial has its own model constrained to the div in which the partial resides. The models are used by knockout for the data and the functionality on the page.

Partial A has some search functionality that returns a bunch of rows with checkboxes. The user can check these checkboxes and click a button. On the click of these buttons, I need to pass the ID field for all the checked rows to a method that will fetch data for these ids and then append the rows of data in Partial B.

I can already populate Partial B using an ajax call made from a javascript method defined on the model for Partial B. The ajax call in turn fetches the data from a controller method. However, I don't know how to call the javascript method from partial A (which doesn't have access to Partial B's model) and how to pass the selected data to the javascript method.

How can I go about this?

Comment: Can you show a mockup of what you have, possibly in Jsfiddle? I'm not sure what you mean by Partial A doesn't have access to Partial Bs model.

Answer (score 0):

If I hear you right, you could do this by having a single viewmodel with 2 models, which is pretty common. So something like this:

```
var viewmodel = function(){
    var 
        self = this,
        self.modelA = { ... },
        self.modelB = { ... },
        self.fetchRowsForB = function () { ... },
        self.fetchCheckedRowsFromA = function(){ ... }
};
```

However, you said that the partials do not know about each other. So another option could be to have a master viewmodel like this:

```
var masterVM = function(){
    var 
        self = this,
        vmA = function() { ... },
        vmB = function() { ... },
        functionThatTalksBetweenTheTwo = function() { ... }    

};
```

This allows you to keep the 2 partials VM's separated, but then when they are put together they can talk to each other.